# Extract the index of largest number in different lines

Tags: python

I am writing a code for extracting specific lines from my file and then look for the maximum number, more specifically for its position (index).
So I start my code looking for the lines:

```
with open (filename,'r') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        for index, line in enumerate(lines):
            if 'a ' in line:
                x=(lines[index])
                print(x)
```

So here from my code I got the lines I was looking for:

```
a 3 4 5
a 6 3 2
```

Then the rest of my code is looking for the maximum between the numbers and prints the index:

```
y = [float(item) for item in x.split()]
                z=y.index(max(y[1:3]))
                print(z)
```

now the code finds the index of the two largest numbers (so for 5 in the first line and 6 in the second):

```
3
1
```

But I want my code compare also the numbers between the two lines (so largest number between 3,4, 5,6,3,2), to have as output the index of the line, where is in the file the line containing the largest number (for example line 300) and the position in line (1).
Can you suggest to me some possible solutions?

Comment: You want to print the index of the maximum element in your file. Is it ?

Comment: Yes exactly, but in specific lines. So I first extracted the lines and then I was looking for the index of the maximum element. However, it prints out two index.

Comment: One question, If it only prints out "1", how would you know which line that index 1 belongs to ?

Comment: Yes, here there is the problem. You are ritght I was not writing it correctly. When I extract the two lines both have index 0 to 3  What I would like to have back is where is the  6, so in which line  between the ones I have extracted and  which position in the line (1). I could get the index of the lines in the first part of the code but then I still need to find the largest number between the two lines I have extracted and the position in line

Comment: Thanks, I will edit the question in the way one can understand.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like that.
`max_value` - list, where you can get max number, line and position

```
max_value = [0, 0, 0]  # value, line, position

with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for index, line in enumerate(lines):
        if 'a ' in line:
            # get line data with digits
            line_data = line.split(' ')[1:]

            # check if element digit and bigger then max value - save it
            for el_index, element in enumerate(line_data):
                if element.isdigit() and int(element) > max_value[0]:
                    max_value = [int(element), index, el_index]

print(max_value)
```

Input data

```
a 3 4 5
a 6 3 2
```

Output data

```
# 6 - is max, 1 - line, 0 - position
[6, 1, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate over every single line and keep track of the line number as well as the position of the items in that line all together. Btw you should run this with python 3.9+ (because of `.startswith()` method.)

```
with open(filename) as f:
    lines = [line.rstrip() for line in f]

max_ = 0
line_and_position = (0, 0)
for i, line in enumerate(lines):
    if line.startswith('a '):

        # building list of integers for finding the maximum
        list_ = [int(i) for i in line.split()[1:]]
        for item in list_:
            if item > max_:
                max_ = item

                # setting the line number and position in that line
                line_and_position = i, line.find(str(item))

print(f'maximum number {max_} is in line {line_and_position[0] + 1} at index {line_and_position[1]}')
```

Input :

```
a 3 4 5
a 6 3 2
a 1 31 4
b 2 3 2
a 7 1 8
```

Output:

`maximum number 31 is in line 3 at index 4`

Answer (score -1):

You can do it like below. I commented each line for explanation. This method differs from the others in that: using `regex` we are getting the current number and it's character position from one source. In other words, there is no going back into the line to find data after-the-fact. Everything we need comes on every iteration of the loop. Also, all the lines are filtered as they are received. Between the 2, having a stack of conditions is eliminated. We end up with 2 loops that get directly to the point and one condition to see if the requested data needs to be updated.

```py
import re


with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    #prime data
    data = (0, 0, 0)
    #store every line that starts with 'a' or blank line if it doesn't
    for L, ln in enumerate([ln if ln[0] is 'a' else '' for ln in f.readlines()]):
        #get number and line properties
        for res in [(int(m.group('n')), L, m.span()[0]) for m in re.compile(r'(?P<n>\d+)').finditer(ln)]:
            #compare new number with current max
            if res[0] > data[0]:
                #store new properties if greater
                data = res
    #print final                
    print('Max: {}, Line: {}, Position: {}'.format(*data))
```